# Every time android studio download plugins?

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded Android studio successfully, I install gradle completely, as I restarted Android studio, again it starts download some plugins, have a look there what's happening in there please help!!

here is a pic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sdk-commons jars are used by other Android tools libraries and saved in to your gradle cache and downloaded once only if there is no change in versions or cache are not deleted/stored(First run).

You can find these jars here

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\.gradle\caches\artifacts-26\filestore\com.android.tools\sdk-common
```